# Get access of all params from other component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular project and I have my module like this :

```js
{
  path: 'cours/:categoryId/chapters/:chapterId',
  component: ChaptersComponent},
},
{
  path: 'cours/:categoryId/chapters/:chapterId/lessons/:lessonsId', 
  component: AppLessonComponent
},
```

And my question is: If in the AppLessonComponent I want to get the `:categoryId` or the `:chapterId` is it possible ? 'Cause when I use `activitedRoute.snapshot.params` it only getting the `:lessonsId` which is logical ... Thanks for helping me

Comment: The activated route should have everything you need. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2qhka3. Click the "Link to Lesson" text and view the console. You should see the values in the `snapshot.params` object.

Comment: Also, I tend to order routes from most to least complex to prevent an unexpected match

Comment: your appLessonComponent should be a child of the chapter component, use the children attribute while defining route. Also activatedRoute.snapshot.parent can give you access to parent attribute

Comment: Might be a good idea to use the `children` property in the first object and place the second object within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the router to make route params available to child route components with [paramsInheritanceStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#paramsInheritanceStrategy)

```js
import {RouterModule, ExtraOptions} from "@angular/router";

export const routingConfiguration: ExtraOptions = {
  paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
};

export const Routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routingConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while, I finally found the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/provideRouter) for how to add the `paramsInheritanceStrategy` in Angular 17

main.ts:

> ```
> const appRoutes: Routes = [];
> bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,
>   {
>     providers: [
>       provideRouter(appRoutes,
>         withDebugTracing(),
>         withRouterConfig({paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'}))
>     ]
>   }
> );
> ```

As mentioned in Drenai's answer, now you can get all the params from the parent routes